# How To Read NFC event?

Tags: windows-7, event-log, event-viewer, nfc

I have an external NFC reader connected via usb to a Windows-7, with the drivers installed.
It seems to work, as when I place a NFC card on the reader its led changes from red to green and the PC makes the typical sound of connecting something via usb. But my ad-hoc program doesn't do anything. 
How can I check with the operating system that the NFC card is being read? Is there something in the Event Viewer that I can see?

The vendor of the external reader only supplies drivers, no additional software is given.

Thanks,

Comment: AFAIK there are no events, especially in the case of Win7 which doesn't even natively support NFC. If you're a developer then in Win8 you can use the ProximityDevice and ProximityMessage classes from the Windows.Networking.Proximity namespace. See [this Intel document](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-nfc-from-windows-8-applications) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, finally the ad-hoc program started to work. It looked like a matter of plugging in an out in different USB ports